# Can I pass a clock signal as an input argument in a Verilog task?

Tags: arguments, task, verilog, clock

I was writing a testbench in VCS(G-2012.09) to verify an SPI module.

Here is a task to get a byte from a SPI master:

```
task get_byte;
begin
    repeat(8) @(posedge spck)
    begin
        if (spss == 1'b0)
            tmp = {tmp[6:0], mosi};
    end
    $display ("[Time:%dns]---->Get a byte: 0x%h", $stime, tmp);
end
endtask
```

It works. Then I want to parameterize this task and replace the code with:

```
task get_byte;
    input clk, oen, din;
    output [7:0] byte;
begin
    byte = 8'd0;
    repeat(8) @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (oen == 1'b0)
            byte = {byte[6:0], din};
    end
    $display ("[Time:%dns]---->Get a byte: 0x%h", $stime, byte);
end
endtask
```

But when I called the task with `get_byte(spck, spss, mosi, tmp)` and run the testbench in VCS, it stucked. It seemed that `spck` did not pass to work as `clk` inside this task.

So is there a rule that a clock signal can not be used as an input argument within a task or did I make anything wrong?

Answer (score 5):

In one of the old stackoverflow questions you can find following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735424/task-in-verilog?rq=1):

> In Verilog arguments are passed to tasks by value. This means that the value of `clock` will be fixed for the lifetime of the call to the task. Your task will never find a `posedge` of `clock`, and will wait forever.

So the answer is: you can use `clk` as an input argument to a task, but it won't work as "standard" clock.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you ask if you declare the task as **automatic** and pass the input by reference (using the **ref** keyword instead of the **input** keyword in the port definition of the task)

Answer (score 0):

Use the clock without declaring it an input, as you did in the first task.  Passing by reference won't work either, since the task will try to set the clock signal at the end of the task, and the simulator will throw an error.

You may want to have several tasks that reference the different clk names, i.e.:

```
get_byte_spclk(...)
get_byte_clk(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Qiu, this will not work.
You however can do one trick.
see the code below:

```
task my_task;
@(posedge testbench.name_of_the_signal_you_want_to_use_as_refernce)
Do something here
endtask
```

So you basically have to give path to the clock signal, something like that:

**testbech.instance_of_instantiated_module.clock_signal_name**